# windows batch too much verbose

Tags: windows, batch-file

Im facing too much verbosity once windows batch is executing this `if` statement:

```
IF EXIST a1.xml IF EXIST b1.xml IF EXIST c1.xml ECHO Please provide singed files into proper directory and wait....
```

once i execute script, in my w10 cmd window everything is printed:

```
....
    D:\MyWork>IF EXIST a1.xml IF EXIST b1.xml IF EXIST c1.xml ECHO Please provide singed files into proper directory and wait....
....
```

how to supress batch to print only what is in the `ECHO` part - i want to see only: `Please provide singed files into proper directory and wait....`

thx for support in advance

Comment: put `@echo off` at the beginning of the script.

Comment: @echo off does not work - if i set it this message is completly suppressed

Comment: is any where in your script `echo on`? May be bigger excerpt of the code will help.

Comment: Then there aren't `echo`'s executed. Perhaps you should use simpler expressions

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you change your line to read:

```bat
@IF EXIST a1.xml IF EXIST b1.xml IF EXIST c1.xml @(ECHO Please provide singed files into proper directory and wait....)
```

If that is okay, change it to two lines, because long lines generally over 80 characters are awful!

```bat
@IF EXIST a1.xml IF EXIST b1.xml IF EXIST c1.xml @(
    ECHO Please provide singed files into proper directory and wait....)
```